# Browser build in image sharpener adds 1px border to the image

Tags: html, css, border, sharp

I've enabled to my browser function that makes images more sharpened.
The issue is - when image got dark background and is over dark background - there is 1px bright border around whole image.

The question is - is there some CSS posibility to disable it.

I was trying to add inner shadow or inner border on an image but it doesn't work.

Solution that seems to work is to either puth the image inside a container and give container inner shadow or border or eventually create :after element which will cover the border.

But the question is - is there some other way to do that.
And - why it gives that kind of border in the first place? Isn't it a browser bug?

Thanks and regards